Compare two dataframe using pyspark in azure data bricks
I have two data frames.
first contains id, inUse, otherId
second contains id, otherId.
first df



id
inUse
otherId




01
true
2304


02
true
5654


03
False
6785


04
True
null


05
False
6785



second df



id
otherId




01
2304


02
5654


04
37584


05
6785



Now I want to get output similar to the following



id
otherId
Presentin col




01
2304
True


02
5654
True


04
37584
false


05
6785
True



is it possible to do this task with the help of for loop ?

Could you please provide sample inputs and output and the approach what you have tried?

You can use below code to achieve your requirement using a for loop:
# Initialize an empty list to store the output data
output_data = []

# Iterate over the rows of the second DataFrame
for index, row in second_df.iterrows():
    # Check if otherId is present in the first DataFrame where inUse is True
    present = ((first_df['otherId'] == row['otherId']) & (first_df['inUse'] == True)).any()
    # Append the result to the output data list
    output_data.append([row['id'], row['otherId'], present])

# Create the output DataFrame
output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_data, columns=['id', 'otherId', 'Presentin col'])

# Display the output DataFrame
print(output_df)

You will get output data frame as shown below:



id
otherId
Presentin col




01
2304
True


02
5654
True


04
37584
False


05
6785
True



Here is the complete code for your reference:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create the first DataFrame
data1 = {
    'id': ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05'],
    'inUse': [True, True, False, True, False],
    'otherId': [2304, 5654, 6785, np.nan, 6785]
}

first_df = pd.DataFrame(data1)

# Create the second DataFrame
data2 = {
    'id': ['01', '02', '04', '05'],
    'otherId': [2304, 5654, 37584, 6785]
}

second_df = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Initialize an empty list to store the output data
output_data = []

# Iterate over the rows of the second DataFrame
for index, row in second_df.iterrows():
    # Check if otherId is present in the first DataFrame where inUse is True
    present = ((first_df['otherId'] == row['otherId']) & (first_df['inUse'] == True)).any()
    # Append the result to the output data list
    output_data.append([row['id'], row['otherId'], present])

# Create the output DataFrame
output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_data, columns=['id', 'otherId', 'Presentin col'])

# Display the output DataFrame
print(output_df)

Alternatively, you can use join operation between two data frames using below code to achieve your requirement:
#Perform the join on the 'id' column
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='right', suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))

# Create the 'Presentin col' column
merged_df['Presentin col'] = merged_df['otherId_df1'] == merged_df['otherId_df2']

# Select and rename the columns to get the final output
final_df = merged_df[['id', 'otherId_df2', 'Presentin col']].copy()
final_df.rename(columns={'otherId_df2': 'otherId'}, inplace=True)

print(final_df)


Will this work for data frames which are not sorted?

could you provide sample data frames which are unsorted?
